# How to get an ISO_A2 page pdf in android?

Tags: android, pdf

When I create a PDF using PdfDocument with the ISO_A2 PrintAttribute set, I'm getting 15.00 x 26.67 page sizes in my PDF when I verify it in Acrobat Reader. Here is the code I'm using:

```
PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A2)
                .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("zooey", PRINT_SERVICE, 1080, 1920))
                .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
                .build();
        PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(this, printAttrs);
        Paint black = new Paint();
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        black.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1080, 1920, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        page.getCanvas().drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, 1080, 1920), black);

        document.finishPage(page);
```

Comment: What version of Android are you running on? The [master branch code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/print/PrintAttributes.java) shows that `PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A2` has the right definition, but it's possible that there were bugs in older editions. Also, why are you passing what look like size values as the resolution?

Comment: I'm running on Android 5.0 (API 21). I replaced the size values with the values that were being passed.